# Convert a Classic Slideshow to an ordinary notebook

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

I have several Classic Slideshow presentations originally created 3 or 4 years ago. I would like to convert these to ordinary Mathematica notebooks, removing all the slideshow-related paraphernalia including page breaks, etc.

If I simply select Format > Stylesheet > Default, the separate slides are still there, labelled "Slide 1 of 34" etc.. Is it then just a matter of manually removing all the page breaks, or is there more to it?

Related to this, (though it's not what I want to do at present), what is the best way to convert from a classic slideshow to the newer Presentation style? Will Format > Stylesheet > PresenterTools do the job correctly?

Comment: Slides appear to be separated by an empty cell with the `SlideShowNavigationBar` style. These are easily removed with a text editor (which works). I don't know a good way to remove them in Mma, but presumably you can select and delete them all.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have the answer you are asking for.

1. Choose `Palettes` in the toolbar
2. Select the `Classic Slide show`.
3. Under  `Settings`, click  `View Environment`.
4. Select `Printout`.

Here are some pics that will show how to do that.

[image][image]